# Backbone.js attach view to multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am rather new to backbone, so its possible that i am violating the very essence of backbone in doing this. Suggestions are appreciated:

I have made a wall sort of system. So there is a form that can be used to post updates on the wall.

Each update can have comments on them. I am showing 10 updates at a time. So there are 10 comment forms. 
So I have a view:

```
    CommentForm=Backbone.View.extend({
initialize:function(messageView){

},
events:{
    "submit":"postcomment"
},
showMessage:function(data){
      if(data.success)
            type="success";
               else
            type="error";
           message=data.error?data.error:"Update posted successfully";
           $messageContainer=$this.prev();
           console.log($this);
           var html="<div class='alert alert-"+type+"'>"+message+"</div>";
            $($messageContainer).html(html);
},
postcomment:function(){
        $this=$(this.el);

        $.post(baseUrl+"/portal/post-comment",$this.serialize(),this.showMessage,"json");
        return false;
}


   });
```

Now I create an instance to it as follows:

```
  commentFormView= new CommentForm({el:$(".comment-form form")});
```

Note that .comment-form is a div. There are multiple such elements. The event handler gets attached to all the comment forms just fine. But when I use `$this=$(this.el);` it always refers to the first comment form. How do I solve this. $(this.el) should refer to the current instance of comment form, where the event was triggered and not the first one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way would be to create a new view for each element using something like this.

```
$(".comment-form form").each(function() {
    new CommentForm( { el: $(this) } );
});
```

---

**Edit** There is another (better?) way.  Because the event handler gets the raw event as its first parameter, you can write the handler `postcomment` like this:

```
postcomment:function(evt){
   // ...
}
```

Then you can use `$(evt.srcElement)` to get the actual element.

```
postcomment:function(evt){
   $this = $(evt.srcElement);
   // ...
}
```

Comment: When I tried this the `evt` parameter didn't contain srcElement, but I was about to use `evt.target`. Turns out that some browsers support `srcElement` and others `originalElement` so jQuery nicely figures out which is which and give it back to you in `target`.

FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

$('.comment-form form') will return an array of all the matching form elements. You need to iterate through that array and create a view for each element, like dbaseman showed.

Also, instead of doing

```
$this=$(this.el)
```

backbone views already provide a jquery wrapped el:

```
this.$el
```