# Attaching event handlers in backbone already in the DOM

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I understand attaching event handlers to views like so:

```
events:{
  'a click':'mymethod'
}
```

But what if I want to attach, say, a click event to something already in the DOM. Something I don't have a view, model or anything for.

**UDATED CODE**:

**app.js:**

```
(function() {

window.Team = {
Models: {},
Collections: {},
Views: {},
Router: {}
};

$(document).ready(function() {

var employees = new Team.Collections.Members();
employees.fetch({

data: { action: 'get_gdw_employees' },

success: function(collection, object, jqXHR){
  var allMembers = new Team.Views.AllMembers({collection: employees });
},

error: function(jqXHR, statusText, error) {
  console.log(error);
}
});

 var foo = new Team.Router.UIEvents();
 Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root:"/about-us/meet-the-team/"});

 });

 })();
```

**app.model.js**

```
Team.Models.Member = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

**app.collections.js**

```
Team.Collections.Members = Backbone.Collection.extend({
 model: Team.Models.Member,
 url: 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'
});
```

**app.views.js**

```
Team.Views.Member = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize:function(){
  this.render();
},

render:function(){
  this.$el.html( this.model.get('firstName'));
  return this;
}

});

Team.Views.AllMembers = Backbone.View.extend({

 initialize:function(){
   this.render();
 },

render:function(){
  this.collection.each(function(member){
    var employee = new Team.Views.Member({model:member});
  }, this);

 return this;
}

});
```

Comment: Is this something inside your view's `el` or elsewhere?

Comment: No. This element is something that does not belong to a view. This is more of a best practice question. Seeing as backbone is really about consistent architecture, I confused as to where this code **should** go.

Comment: Binding outside your `el` smells bad. You'd generally use an event bus instead: some other view listens to that `a click`, calls [`events.trigger('some-custom-event')`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-trigger) on the global event bus, your view listens. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10697864/479863 and  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16516658/479863 have some examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
$('thatThingSelector').bind('click', function(){...});
```

**EDITED**

From an architectural point of view, in a Backbone based application (SPA) every interaction must be implemented using Backbone, otherwise it would be a new kind of spaghetti :).

When you say that there is a part of your page that the user can interact with, it sounds like it should be wrapped in a View, because a View doesn't necessarily need a model it could be, as in your case, some interactive part of the application.

Comment: Sure, I know HOW. But where does this belong in the Backbone Architecture?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use backbone to handle DOM events you need to attach that part of DOM to a backbone view.

It's actually pretty easy to attach a backbone view to an existing part of DOM.

### Markup

```
<div id="existing-element">
    <button id="my-button"/>
</div>
```

### View

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({

      el: '#existing-element',

      events:{
       'click #my-button' : 'onClick'
      },

      onClick: function(){
        //handle click event
      }
});
```

Comment: Aha, ok. What if I want to add to multiple elements. Say, all elements with '.some-class'?

Comment: @JustinWHall take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701338/backbone-js-attach-view-to-multiple-elements